# GET http://localhost:3000/public/js/test.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, node.js, liquid

I tried to connect sign_up.liquid with test.js. But I have the error 404.

I think my path to connect this two files are correct:

```
  <script src="../../public/js/test.js"> </script>
  <form id="formSignUp" method="POST" onsubmit="return main()">
    <h1>Inscription</h1>
    <input type="text" id="form_input_name" name="name" placeholder="Prénom" size= "30">
    <input type="text" id="form_input_surname" name="surname" placeholder="Nom" size= "30">
    <input type="text" id="form_input_mail" name="mail" placeholder="E-mail" size= "30">
    <input type="password" id="form_input_password" name="password" placeholder="Mot de passe" size= "30">
    <input type="password" id="form_input_conf_password" name="conf_password" placeholder="Confirmation de mot de passe" size= "30">

    <div id="div_checkNewsletter">
        <input type="hidden" name="newsletter" value="0">
        <input type="checkbox" id="box_newsletter" name="newsletter" value="1">
        <label for="newsletter">En cochant cette case, j’accepte de recevoir <br>les actualités d’Otablo.</label>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" id="button_orange_center"> Suivant</button>
</form>
```

[image]

And my server.js make a way to send my static files to the client:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const path = require('path')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const http = require('http').createServer(app)

// Liqui Param
const { Liquid } = require('liquidjs')
const engine = new Liquid({
  root: ['./views', './views/partials', './views/layouts']
})

const HTML_DIR = path.join(__dirname, '/public/')
app.use(express.static(HTML_DIR))

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
```

I don't understand why `sign_up.liquid` and `test.js` are not linked.

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Answer (score 3):

> I think my path to connect this two files are correct

It isn't.

The path is what you specify **in your server.js file** and not on your computers file system.

You said:

> ```
> const HTML_DIR = path.join(__dirname, '/public/')
> app.use(express.static(HTML_DIR))
> ```

… so everything in `/public/` gets mapped to URLs under `/`.

That means the path is:

```
src="/js/test.js"
```